# UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1: Why does it work for the most of the time and why sometimes not?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a osCommerce 2.2 MST which has some custom additions to it. osCommerce itself is in ISO-8859-1. The addition has a table in a MySQL database which is now in utf8_general_ci (the others are all in latin1_swedish_ci). The php-file I'm calling outputs

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

As I mentioned before the data from the database is in UTF-8. But letters like ö,ä,ü are correct displayed. How can this be? There should be no `utf8_decode`. But the letter č is displayed as `?`. I get this directly as result array. If I make the query with phpmyadmin it is correct displayed.

I managed to get all letters correct displayed (only in one section of the script). This is what I made

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

In the php-script I also added

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

But then other problems occured.

What I want to know why data in UTF-8 is "correctly" displayed when it should be not. And how do I get the letter č correctly displayed?

The system is I find rather complex. Where and how can I look what is wrong here?

Comment: A good start is the PHP Charset FAQ: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html

Comment: Another great resource http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Comment: @hakre: Nice link! Thanks! I wished I had this before I were searching for hours for an solution for this ...

Comment: Remember "N'DUUH!": Never Don't Use UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the sequence of encodings/decodings that your data go through, but the reason that letters like ö, ä, and ü are correct, while č is not, is that ö, ä, and ü can be encoded in ISO-8859-1, but č cannot. You will need to use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 in your HTML to get č to display.

Comment: I tried it long before, but I didn't worked. I still get the `?`. But I also think you are right, because č is not in the character set of ISO-8859-1. The question is where is this defined? I can add the header code but than ö and č are not working anymore. I edit the client connection with `SET NAMES 'utf8'` but than many other things won't work. Is it possible to do this without changing the client connection for all queries? Is it possible to do this only for one query?

Comment: How can I get sure that my data is correctly stored as UTF-8 in the database? If I use phpmyadmin for the query everything is displayed correctly. phpMyAdmin also uses `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` so I think the data is correct.

Comment: If the only character that is giving a problem is č, then you can replace every occurrence of it in the generated HTML with the character escape sequence: `&#269;` or `&#x10D;`. (Even if more than one character is giving a problem, if there aren't too many, this may be the easiest approach.)

Comment: But how do I know if it is a č? The result of the query gives me a `?` and this could be everything ...

Comment: @testing - The only way forward, then, is to use UTF-8 and figure out why the HTML is being encoded as ISO-8859-1. Perhaps update your question to show the actual code that generates the document.

Comment: What do you mean with "use UTF-8"? The problem with showing the code is that it is too much (include from include). I think the only way is either to have only the ISO-8859-1 characters or change everything to UTF-8. And for my question: I think the results from the queries are all in ISO-8859-1. That is the reason why only ISO-8859-1 characters work.

Comment: And the funniest thing is the same files on an other php/mysql version gives me UTF-8. Do you have an idea about that? `default_charset` is not set (at both) in the php.ini.